# Keycloak Integration with Flowable

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, keycloak, flowable

I have an app that has Flowable Open Source as a module. To use my roles and users in keycloak, flowable IDM is integrated with the keycloak with this config.

```
....
flowable:
  common:
    app:
      idm-admin:
        user: <user>
        password: <password>
      security:
        type: oauth2
        o-auth2:
          authorities-attribute: groups
          groups-attribute: ${IAM_USERGROUP:userGroups}
  idm:
    app:
      keycloak:
        enabled: false
        server: ${ISSUER_URL:http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/my-realm}
        authentication-realm: master
        authentication-user: ${IAM_AUTHUSER:admin}
        realm: ${IAM_REALM:my-realm}
        authentication-password: ${IAM_AUTHPASS:admin}
....
```

**Now my issue here is, when I logged into my main application I have already necessary roles, but when a user tries to go flowable module, it redirects the user to login page as if user has not authenticated or authorized yet.**

This is my security config for the microservice which contains flowable

```
http
                .requestMatchers()
                    .antMatchers("/actuator/**")
                    .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/actuator/**").permitAll()
                    .and()
                .requestMatchers()
                    .antMatchers("/graphql/**")
                    .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated()
                    .and()
                    .oauth2Login(oauthLogin -> oauthLogin.permitAll())  //redirect to login if no token or session is provided
                    .oauth2ResourceServer().jwt(); //validate JWT Bearer token

        http.logout()
                .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/app/logout"))
                .logoutSuccessHandler(keycloakLogoutHandler);
```

Only actuator and graphql endpoints customized regarding security. So basically I leave all authentication and authorization config to the flowable classes. What am I doing wrong here?

versions
spring boot 2.6.2

flowable-spring-boot-starter 6.7.2

Answer (score 0):

I think the configuration is a bit off versus how i have configured flowable / keycloak integration succesfully. Change this

```
server: ${ISSUER_URL:http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/my-realm}
```

to be

```
server: http://localhost:8080
```

It should not be the same as the issuer URL.